# Yocto getcap: command not found

Tags: yocto, openembedded, linux-capabilities

I'm updating our yocto from fido to morty, and have been migrating recipes and such to work with it, but now I dont have `getcap` on the target.

I checked that PATH is correctly set up:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin...
```

and that there is no `getcap` in `/usr/bin/` as there should be.

I understood that libcap should provide these, and I have libcap as dependency on multiple recipe, which build just fine, so I don't understand why they are not installed on the target.

I have no clue where to start looking for the problem, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at build output from `libcap`, for instance `${WORKDIR}/packages-split`, you'll see that the following packages have been created:

```
libcap
libcap-bin
libcap-dbg
libcap-dev
libcap-doc
libcap-locale
libcap-staticdev
```

The actual library has been put into `libcap`, while the helper binaries has been put into `libcap-bin`.